# How do i create a view table to show current number of record of the same employee and the total count? SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i create a view to show the number of total records by name?

```
CREATE VIEW ViewTest AS
SELECT First_Name || ' ' || last_Name As EMP_NAME,
       to_char(READ_DATE, 'YYYY-MON') As MONTH
  FROM EMPLOYEE E
 INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_READ ER
    ON E.EMP_ID = ER.EMP_ID
 WHERE to_char(READ_DATE, 'YYYY-MON') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MON');
```

This outputs:

```
+-------------+----------+
|  EMP_NAME   |  MONTH   |
+-------------+----------+
| Morty_Smith | 2020-NOV |
| Morty_Smith | 2020-NOV |
| Morty_Smith | 2020-NOV |
+-------------+----------+
```

I am looking to get an output like this..

```
+-------------+----------+-------+
|  EMP_NAME   |  MONTH   | COUNT |
+-------------+----------+-------+
| MORTY SMITH | 2020-NOV |     3 |
+-------------+----------+-------+
```

And assuming I have another person with a different name, the view will show this..

```
+-------------+----------+---------+
|  EMP_NAME   |  MONTH   |  COUNT  |
+-------------+----------+---------+
| MORTY SMITH | 2020-NOV |    3    |
| JERRY SMITH | 2020-NOV |    1    |
+-------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Do you need to include `emp_id` with the view also, as originally stated ?

Comment: I guess as @Tejash has commented, using emp_id would be a better practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count()` aggregation with group by

```
SELECT First_Name ||' '||last_Name As EMP_NAME, 
       to_char(READ_DATE,'YYYY-MON') As MONTH ,count(*) as cnt
FROM EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_READ ER ON E.EMP_ID = ER.EMP_ID
WHERE to_char(READ_DATE,'YYYY-MON') = to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MON')
group by First_Name ||' '||last_Name,to_char(READ_DATE,'YYYY-MON')
```

Comment: If two employees have same name then there count will be combined. It is good practice to always use emp_id in group by.

Comment: Understood. i will do that! thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `GROUP BY` clause along with `COUNT` aggregation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ViewTest AS
SELECT First_Name || ' ' || last_Name As EMP_NAME,
       TO_CHAR(READ_DATE, 'YYYY-MON') As MONTH,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM EMPLOYEE E
 INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_READ ER
    ON E.EMP_ID = ER.EMP_ID
 WHERE TO_CHAR(READ_DATE, 'YYYY-MON') = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MON')
 GROUP BY First_Name || ' ' || last_Name, TO_CHAR(READ_DATE, 'YYYY-MON')
```

Comment: If two employees have same name then there count will be combined. It is good practice to always use emp_id in group by.

Comment: originally my answer was containing emp_id also, but the question has changed @Tejash as you should have noticed.

Comment: Yes. I removed that because it keeps returning column ambiguously defined..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query using `GROUP BY`:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewTest AS
SELECT EMP_ID AS ID,
       First_Name ||' '||last_Name As EMP_NAME,
       to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MON') As MONTH, -- you can use SYSDATE here. No need to include it in GROUP BY
       Count(1) as "COUNT"
  FROM EMPLOYEE E 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_READ ER
   ON E.EMP_ID = ER.EMP_ID
WHERE to_char(READ_DATE,'YYYY-MON') = to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MON')
GROUP BY EMP_ID,
         First_Name,
         Last_name
```